# Access 2003 Select records with null time

Tags: ms-access, time, null

I have been asked to produce a report from an Access database of the number of jobs that have an entry of 0:00:00 in a time field EstimatedManHours.

However when I try I get no dataset back.  Even if I browse the table directly in Access 2003, place my cursor in the cell EstimatedManHours which has a value of 0:00:00 and click on "filter by selection" I suddenly get a zero record dataset even though I know there are thousands that meet this criteria.

Any help or guidance would be greatly received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that you are displaying an input mask and that the actual value is null, so:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.EstimatedManHours
FROM Table t
WHERE t.EstimatedManHours Is Null
```

Comment: Thanks Remou, sorry I should have stated that I have already tried SELECT dbo_tasks.ExpectedDownTime, dbo_tasks.EstimatedManHours
FROM dbo_tasks
WHERE dbo_tasks.EstimatedManHours is null;             but I get an empty dataset

Comment: Are you dsaying that these are SQL Server tables (dbo) linked to MS Access and you wish to run the query in MS Access?

Comment: Yes.  I have been given only access to the .mdb, but I believe that the data is held in a linked table in SQL Server.  I can only get at data via this .mdb sadly.  Does this greatly affect the dialect of the query?

Comment: It just adds a number of other possibilities. Try test for the time element only `SELECT TimeValue(EstimatedManHours)`. Also check for text `WHERE EstimatedManHours = "0:00:00"` or if you know VBA, see what that sees the field as.

Comment: Thanks Remou I can now select using                              where TimeValue(EstimatedManHours) = 0